# Configure mesh network xbee pro S2

Tags: java, serial-port, embedded, xbee

I have one coordinator, 1 router and 2 end devices, E1 and E2. I want to configure mesh network. router is the parent node of my both end devices. I want to send data from coordinator --> end device E1 via router. So should I send data to router and it will also send to child end device or I send data to end device directly and router will take care of it. I am working in API mode using Java. I am newbie and little bit confused.

Answer (score 0):

To your end device of course, as long as your end device in the coordinator range it gona receive its packets, other wise the router gona receive and reroutes the packets for desired node.

Comment: But i require to pass the message via router. The coordinator has to send data to the destination via routers available in the path. Should i opt for routing tables ?

Comment: No, the network manages packet delivery.  You address the packet, and the mesh determines how to deliver it.  Each end device has a parent device that is responsible for queuing messages while the end device is sleeping.  But you shouldn't need to worry about that -- just be aware that the parent typically queues just a single message for a child end device.